# The Freestyle check box in the Render tab reads "Freestyle SVG Export" instead of "Freestyle"

Tags: export, freestyle

I'm using Blender 2.91.  I've watched a couple of videos where the plugin is called "Freestyle"  However, when I enable the only plugin I can find Preferences -> add-ons it called itself "Freestyle SVG Editor."  I cannot find an add-on just called "Freestyle"
As a result, I do not have a "Freestyle" option below Image, Alpha, and Depth in the Render Layer box of the compositor.

The goal is to export a mesh network as a 2 dimensional SVG for importing to tools such as Inkscape.  I just need to export a rather simple wireframe.

Am I doing something wrong so I can't find a "Freestyle" add-on but only a "Freestyle SVG Editor" add-on in version 2.91?  How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you referring to https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/freestyle/introduction.html?

Comment: Yes, exactly.
See also https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/freestyle/export_svg.html
Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the correct tab is "Freestyle SVG Exporter" as introduced officially into Blender in [this commit](https://github.com/blender/blender-addons/commit/c6595a3584e3f59018a8ad86a7de3d0c2bf4105a#diff-057d283d349952999771b3032aa66ee84b0620a57e4b3aa8850b7e8fdb24cbb9) in 2014 which had more unwieldy title of "Export Freestyle edges to an .svg format" with it [shortly thereafter](https://github.com/blender/blender-addons/commit/8bab4c18593bb366259173dc1462818371b882cd#diff-057d283d349952999771b3032aa66ee84b0620a57e4b3aa8850b7e8fdb24cbb9) being changed to "Freestyle SVG Exporter", which is where it currently resides.

Poking around tutorials for Freestyle, a lot of them date from about 2013, which makes me think that the initial plugin source (which I'm having a difficult time locating at the moment) may have simply gone with "Freestyle".